# I have to send two variables about and product to another page in php

Tags: php, html, forms

The two variables are `about` and `product`, they are coming from a form.

```php
<?php  
$about= $_POST['about'];
$product= $_POST['products'];
?>
```

```php
<?php
if (empty($company)) {
    header("Location: templatewithoutcompany.php?product" = . $product&about = . $about);  
}
?>
```

I can successfully send one variable but when I try to send multiple variables, I get an error.

Comment: Did you check that you used the same name for products? It reads products in the first part but product in the second part.

Comment: I think you meant header("Location: templatewithoutcompany.php?product=".$product."&about=".$about);

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code. Try changing it to this:

```
<?php  
$about = $_POST['about'];
$product = $_POST['products'];
?>


<?php
if (empty($company)) {
header("Location: templatewithoutcompany.php?product=" . $product . "&about=" . $about);  
}
?>
```

Comment: No worries! Syntax errors become very visible when you make a habit of putting spaces around assignments (`=`), comparisons (`==`), string concatenations (`.`), and other things that go between other things. It's a good habit to always format your code for this very reason.

Comment: I'll be careful of this. Thanks again!